# fwrite there got bug, but i don't know how?

Tags: c

help me solve this coding... it keeps said got errors :-

it said `fwrite` there got problems..

```
// #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

    struct prod
    {
        char ProductCode [5];
        int Expired_year;
        char Product_country [25];
    }product;
    struct prod product;

void main()
{

    char x ;
    FILE* data;
    data = fopen("product.dat","wb");

    while(x != 'N')
    {
        printf("Enter product code :");
        scanf("%s", product.ProductCode);
        printf("Enter expired year of the product :");
        scanf("%d", &product.Expired_year);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter product country :");
        scanf("%[^\n]", product.Product_country);
        fflush(stdin);

        fwrite(&prod, sizeof(product), 1, data);

        printf("\nPlease enter anykey to continue or 'N' to stop: ");
        scanf("%c", &x);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(data);

}
```

Comment: I would call that code "C", not "C++".

Comment: You should tell us what the errors are.

Comment: the line fwrite(&prod, sizeof(product), 1, data);

Comment: That's a line. Tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 3):

```
fwrite(&prod, sizeof(product), 1, data);
```

`prod` doesn't refer to a `struct` instance but to the name of the structure, it should be

```
fwrite(&product, sizeof(product), 1, data);
```

Comment: why prod is not the name of struct? i am do it based on the syntax

Comment: `prod` is the name of the type, not any actual variable.

Comment: is it the first parameter for fwrite is variable name?

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax for `fwrite()`.
It should be,

```
fwrite(&product, 1, sizeof(product), data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument needs a pointer to some data, but &prod is not valid. prod is a type, not an instance variable. You probably want to change it to `fwrite (&product, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're declaring `struct prod product` twice.
Second, the correct sintax for `fwrite()` is `fwrite(&product,sizeof(struct prod),1,data);`